# jQuery UI tooltip on pseudo disabled elements

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I would like to show a [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) on a text input that has a `ui-state-disabled` class.

I took a peek to the [tooltip source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/main/ui/widgets/tooltip.js) and I couldn't find something that checks against that particular class. So I don't know why it won't show.

As far as I can tell, the elements aren't disabled *per se*, they just have a class applied to them.

So, how can I show a tooltip on elements that have that class? I don't want to use a wrapper or anything like that. Maybe extending through widget factory...

Here's a sample code

**HTML**

```
<input name="#1" class="text" data-tooltip="message A">
<input name="#2" class="text" data-tooltip="message B">
<br>
<button id="disable">disable input #2</button>
<button id="enable">enable input #2</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".text").each(function()
{
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: $(this).data("tooltip"),
        items: ".text"      
    });
});

$("#disable").click(function()
{
    $("input[name='#2']").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
});

$("#enable").click(function()
{
    $("input[name='#2']").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
});
```

**FIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/hn1o4qs2/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I've stated in my question, I needed to get this working without adding a container or anything like that. And I was willing to extend the widget somehow...

So I read the source code more carefully and searched throught the whole repository for `ui-state-disabled`, and found that in widget.js there is an `_on()` method that at some point performs a check against that class and a flag called `suppressDisabledCheck`

A comment in code says

```
// Allow widgets to customize the disabled handling
// - disabled as an array instead of boolean
// - disabled class as method for disabling individual parts
```

This was very important, it gave me the clue that this check could be overriden. So a quick search in google and [the widget factory had the answer](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_on):

> Automatically handles disabled widgets: If the widget is disabled or
> the event occurs on an element with the ui-state-disabled class, the
> event handler is not invoked. Can be overridden with the
> suppressDisabledCheck parameter.

So basically I did this:

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip,
{
    options: {
        allowOnDisabled: false
    },
    _on: function()
    {
        var instance = this;

        this._super(instance.options.allowOnDisabled, {
            mouseover: "open",
            focusin: "open",
            mouseleave: "close",
            focusout: "close"
        });
    }
});
```

And then used it like this:

```
$(".text").each(function()
{
    $(this).tooltip({
        allowOnDisabled: true,
        content: $(this).data("tooltip"),
        items: ".text"      
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2022-09-15**

I was having some trouble with this implementation, so I've changed it a little bit

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip,
{
    options: {
        allowOnDisabled: false
    },
    _create: function()
    {
        this._super();

        var instance = this;

        this._on(instance.options.allowOnDisabled, {
            mouseover: "open",
            focusin: "open",
            mouseleave: "close",
            focusout: "close"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See the doc (http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/):

> In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events.
> Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for
> disabled elements, since we need to listen to events to determine when
> to show and hide the tooltip. As a result, jQuery UI does not
> guarantee any level of support for tooltips attached to disabled
> elements. Unfortunately, this means that if you require tooltips on
> disabled elements, you may end up with a mixture of native tooltips
> and jQuery UI tooltips.

### Solution with wrapper

Your HTML:

```
<span class="input-container" data-tooltip="message A">
  <input name="#1" class="text">
</span>
<span class="input-container" data-tooltip="message B">
  <input name="#2" class="text">
</span>
<br>
<button id="disable">
disable input #2
</button>
<button id="enable">
enable input #2
</button>
```

Your Javascript

```
$(".input-container").each(function()
{
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: $(this).data("tooltip"),
        items: ".input-container"      
    });
});
// ... The rest is the same
```

### Solution with fake disabled-property

Here you can use a `readonly` attribute and a custom class for disabled input.

**Playground**: https://jsfiddle.net/5gkx8qec/

Comment: But the elements are not actually disabled

Comment: Thank you, but I've stated that I don't want to use a wraper

Comment: I just added a jsfiddle where you can see how to change your approach. Instead of set them as disabled, try to set them as readonly adding a custom class that you can use to style them or for any kind of condition. Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but you are going in a different direction. I'm about to post an aswer soon

Comment: Ok. Great you've found a solution :)